# How do I place inserted PDF pages via "copypages" flush with top of the page?

Tags: context

I am attempting to use `copypages` to insert multi-page PDFs into my ConTeXt document. I would like to scale the inserted pages so that they appear smaller but place them flush with the top of each page of my new document. How can I do so?

The default behavior appears to center the scaled pages in the center of each page of the new document.

Here's a MWE of the default behavior (assuming you supply a PDF document of your own to insert).

```
\starttext
\copypages[a.pdf][][height=\textheight]
\stoptext
```

---

UPDATE (2020-02-06):

Using layers, I've successfully place one inserted page at the correct location, but it cannot handle multi-page PDFs or multiple PDFs. Here's the MWE I'm working from:

```
\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [setups=layer,background={foreground,insert}]

\definelayer[insert][height=10in]

\starttext
\showframe
~
\getfiguredimensions[02.pdf]\dorecurse\noffigurepages{\setuptexttexts
  [{\setlayerframed
      [insert]
      []
      []
      {\externalfigure[02.pdf][page=\recurselevel]}}]}

\stoptext
```

For context, I am attempting to "Bates stamp" a series of PDFs. I would like to place a page number at the bottom of each page, and to shrink each inserted PDF page such that the newly placed page number does not overlap the inserted PDF pages. I do NOT need a header line on the included pages. `copypages` provides the right functionality to insert the PDFs, but it places the inserted PDF pages in the center of the page, not flush to the top of the paper.

---

UPDATE (2020-03-03):

For future reference, here is a working version of what I'm looking for. 
Note that this code also includes commands for typesetting a specially formatted page number.

Thank you to Wolfgang Schuster for your guidance!

```
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]
\setuppapersize[letter]
\setuplayout[width=6.5in,height=10in,topspace=0.5in,backspace=1in,
  header=0.5in,footer=0.5in]
\setupheadertexts 

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background={foreground,tmp,numbering}]
\definelayer
  [numbering]
  [height=\paperheight,
   width=\paperwidth]
\setuptexttexts
  [{\setlayerframed
      [numbering]
      [preset=middlebottom,
       voffset=0.25in]
      [frame=off]
      {RA/\pagenumber}}]

\definelayout
  [topaligned]
  [header=0pt]

\showframe

\starttext

\startlayout[topaligned]
\copypages[M-654.pdf][][height=10.5in]
\copypages[M-654.pdf][][height=10.5in]
\stoplayout

\stoptext
```

First Page of Output: [image]

Comment: `\copypages` is just a thin wrapper around `\externalfigure`.  You can do the same with just `\getfiguredimensions[a.pdf]\dorecurse\noffigurepages{\externalfigure[a.pdf][page=\recurselevel]}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thanks. That helps me tremendously, although I am still searching for the exact look for what I want.

In particular, I'm trying to get the included PDF flush with the very top of the page (in the top margin). I've been playing with ```\externalfigure``` and ```\placefigure```, but I haven't figured out how best to slide the included PDF to the top of the page.

Comment: For this I'd just put it in a layer, which you can position manually. https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers

Comment: Do you need a header line on the included pages or should the space be empty.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster: I do not need a header line on the included pages. I've updated my original query to clarify.

Comment: @HenriMenke: My attempt to craft a solution using your two suggestions is so far unsuccessful. I've updated my query with my current MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two method available to push the included images or pages to the top of the page. As can be seen in the following example we have to go over the gap which is created by the top space on the page and the height of the header line.

```
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setuppapersize[A7]

\showframe

\starttext

\externalfigure[mill][width=\textwidth]

\stoptext
```

[image]

When you rely on `\externalfigure` to include the page one by one you can use the `\offset` comman to shift each image upwards with the values stored in the `\topspace` and `\headerheight` registers.

The downside of this method is that you have to use `\getfiguredimensions` to get number of pages and use `\dorecurse` to create a loop to include each page.

```
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setuppapersize[A7]

\definemeasure [topskip] [\dimexpr\headerheight+\topspace\relax]

\showframe

\starttext

\offset[y=-\measure{topskip}]{\externalfigure[mill][width=\textwidth]}

\stoptext
```

[image]

The second method you can use and which also works `\copypages` uses a modified layout for the figure pages. The changes of these pages is that we set the height of the `topspace` and the `header` to `0pt` which gets rid of the unwanted space and the images are now aligned with the top margin of the paper.

```
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setuppapersize[A7]

\definelayout
  [topaligned]
  [topspace=0pt,
   header=0pt]

\showframe

\starttext

\startlayout[topaligned]
\externalfigure[mill][width=\textwidth]
\stoplayout

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful solution. I'm using the latter of the two. I'm only using the `header=0pt` option. I omit the `topspace` option, which when set to zero shifts the included image from `copypages` too high. I am updating my original question with a working example of what I'm looking for.